# 301 redirect non-www to www in subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, joomla

I am in a unique situation where I have multiple instances of Joomla setup under my primary domain in different subdirectories.

For example:

example.com = Joomla instance

example.com/subdirectory1 = Another Joomla instance

example.com/subdirectory2 = Another Joomla instance

On the main Joomla instance I was able to forward my non-www pages to www using the htaccess file and this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to also forward non-www pages to www pages on all of the subdirectories.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Since each subdirectory has it's own Joomla instance, is there something I can just add to each of the htaccess files?

I have tried adding this line the the .htaccess files within the subdirectories:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

However, it actually forwards the non-www pages to www.example.com and removes the subfolder from the URL.

I have searched this issue for days but have only come up empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Move those three lines out of your .htaccess and into the Apache config. That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, your Rewrite options are working for only root directory. You can move these options to **conf/httpd.conf** file. So it will be effect to all pages.